# replacing df.append with pd.concat when building a new dataframe from file read

Tags: pandas, dataframe

...

```
header = pd.DataFrame() 


for x in {0,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,21,23}:
    header = header.append({'col1':data1[x].split(':')[0],
                            'col2':data1[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col3':data2[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col4':data2[x]==data1[x],
                            'col5':'---'},
                          ignore_index=True)`
```

...

I have some Jupyter Notebook code which reads in 2 text files to data1 and data2 and using a list I am picking out specific matching lines in both files to a dataframe for easy display and comparison in the notebook

Since df.append is now being bumped for pd.concat what's the tidiest way to do this

is it basically to replace the inner loop code with
...

```
header = pd.concat(header, {all the column code from above })
```

...

addtional input to comment below
Yes, sorry for example the next block of code does this:

```
for x in {4,2 5}:
    header = header.append({'col1':SOMENEWROWNAME'',
                            'col2':data1[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col3':data2[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col4':data2[x]==data1[x],
                            'col5':float(data2[x].split(':'},[1]([-1]) -float(data1[x].split(':'},[1]([-1])
                          ignore_index=True)`
```

repeated 5 times with different data indices in the loop, and then a different SOMENEWROWNAME

I inherited this notebook and I see now that this way of doing it was because they only wanted to do a numerical float difference on the columns where numbers come

but there are several such blocks, with different lines in the data and where that first parameter SOMENEWROWNAME is the different text fields from the respective lines in the data.

so I was primarily just trying to fix these append to concat warnings, but of course if the code can be better written then all good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension and DataFrame constructor:

```
data = [{'col1':data1[x].split(':')[0],
         'col2':data1[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
         'col3':data2[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
         'col4':data2[x]==data1[x],
         'col5':'---'} for x in {0,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,21,23}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

EDIT:

```
out = []
#sample
for x in {1,7,30}:
    out.append({'col1':SOMENEWROWNAME'',
                            'col2':data1[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col3':data2[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col4':data2[x]==data1[x],
                            'col5':float(data2[x].split(':'},[1]([-1]) -float(data1[x].split(':'},[1]([-1]))))))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

---

```
out1 = []
#sample
for x in {1,7,30}:
    out1.append({another dict})))

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(out1)

 df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Or:

```
final = []
for x in {4,2,5}:
    final.append({'col1':SOMENEWROWNAME'',
                            'col2':data1[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col3':data2[x].split(':')[1][:-1],
                            'col4':data2[x]==data1[x],
                            'col5':float(data2[x].split(':'},[1]([-1]) -float(data1[x].split(':'},[1]([-1]))))))


for x in {4,2, 5}:
    final.append({another dict})))

 df = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

Comment: Thanks this was nice of course, but later in the notebook I then have different "lists of row indices" where I do different operations and then want to append

so I should use your list comprehension to build a new "data" and then instead of the dataframe constructor use

    df = pd.concat(df, data)

?

Comment: @DM71 - Can you be more specific? Because `concat` is possible use ony with DataFrames, so need list of DataFrames, solution should be `df = pd.concat([df] + [pd.DataFrame(data)])`

Comment: sorry I added the extra info the original post. I was so pleased to see the tidier setup of the DF that I forgot that this block is repeated, and continues to append using different rows from the data file but with different processing on the "col4" and "col5" (in real life these are called MATCH doing a text based match and DELTA doing a numeric difference, I wanted to anonymise the column names :)


so if I interpret correctly I should just use the first solution, list comprehend a new dataframe and concat those two, repeating for the extra blocks

thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @DM71 - Answer was edited - need append values to helper lists, create DataFrames and last use `concat`, or create one big list `final` and last call DatFrame cosntructor.